# Using powershell to search for a pattern

Tags: regex, powershell, expression

I am trying to write a powershell script to search for a pattern in a text file. Specifically I am looking at reading a file line by line and returning any line that has a space at the 32nd character position.

I have this so far but it just returns all lines that have white space. I need to narrow it down to the 32nd position

Get-Content -path C:\VM_names.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match "\s+"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
-match '^.{31} '
```

Explanation:

```
^ - beginning of the string
. - any character
{31} - repeated 31 times
   - a space
```

Comment: Awesome. That works like a charm. thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really easy to do. By default, `Get-Content` reads a text file as an array of strings (individual lines), unless you use the `-Raw` parameter, which reads it as a single string. You can use the `-match` PowerShell operator to "match" the lines that meet your regular expression.

```
(Get-Content -Path c:\VM_names.txt) -match '^.{31}\s'
```

The result of the above command is an array of lines that match the desired regular expression.

**NOTE**: The call to `Get-Content` must be wrapped in parentheses, otherwise the PowerShell parser will think that `-match` is a parameter on that command.

**NOTE2**: As a good practice, use single quotes around strings, unless you specifically know that you need double quotes. You'll save yourself from accidental interpolation.